# Apache 500 Error with PHP Fun

Tags: php, apache, timeout, execution, max

So I am running a PHP script on my godaddy (don't hate me) virtual server which I am expecting to take around 5 minutes to finish executing. The script is CURLing pages but never holds more than 1 page at a time (it is done in a loop reusing the same variable).
I modified my php5.ini file to the following:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 64M
```

I verified through phpinfo that the ini file changes had taken effect, however I am getting an Apache 500 error after 120 seconds. Here is the error log for this time:

```
[Wed Jul 11 22:08:52 2012] [warn] [client **.**.**.***] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in   120 seconds
[Wed Jul 11 22:08:52 2012] [error] [client **.**.**.***] Premature end of script headers: test.php
```

If anyone has any ideas on why I might be getting these errors or any suggestion on things to try I would appreciate the help. I did notice an option in the php settings set at 120, but I'm not sure if it would have an effect: realpath_cache_tt

I also set a time limit in the .php file: set_time_limit( 600 );

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE:***
Here is what I tried in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
IPCCommTimeout  7200
</IfModule>
```

The  causes an Apache 500 error on any page load.
***I also disabled FastCGI but the issue is still occuring.***

**RESOLVED**
RobB suggested the following:
    
      IPCCommTimeout  7200
    
Which should have worked however due to my godaddy shared hosting it is not allowed. Time to find a new hosting service.

Comment: Have you tried running this locally? XAMPP or Uniserver can both be run locally (on a flash drive even). It would at least rule out a problem with GoDaddy's craptastic hosting options...

Comment: I have not and will try, but in the meantime I am hoping there is something I have missed in the php.ini file. I am trying to disable FastCGI just to see what will happen.

Comment: And of course when I try to disable FastCGI godaddy gives me a connection issue, I think I need to setup a Uniserver!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure of the handling with this issue on GoDaddy but the normal resolution would be as follows:

The issue that you are experiencing is due to FastCGI executing a PHP script but it doesn't generate a response within the default IO timeout (120 seconds), which results in the 500 Internal Server Error.

Try editing the default VirtualHost conf file, typically located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and add this directive inside the `<VirtualHost>` context:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   IPCCommTimeout  7200
</IfModule>
```

After saving the modification, restart apache2 with this command: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

From what I've been able to determine from GoDaddy is that the maximum time limit is 120 seconds for PHP/FastCGI in shared hosting, which can not be increased by the client.  I would suggest contacting their support for assistance and hopefully their reputation won't serve up and you'll be able to get help.

**Update:**
Not sure if it will help but you could try changing from FastCGI to PHP5 in your hosting control center (Settings > File Extension > php5).

Comment: A ticket on godaddy said this should be inserted in the .htaccess file, which I tried, however it breaks the site. Is there somewhere else this should go?

Comment: Aside from modifying the `conf` file as directed above or the `.htaccess` file, I'm not aware of any.  One of the uses of the `.htaccess` file is to modify system settings for the provided directory/website.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it breaks the site"?

Comment: Sorry, it makes it so a 500 error is thrown on any page load.

Comment: Modify your question and paste the contents of your `.htaccess` file if possible.

Comment: The log file says:
/var/chroot/home/content/07/8495407/html/.htaccess: IPCCommTimeout not allowed here
[Wed Jul 11 22:42:50 2012] [alert] [client 24.59.60.251] /var/chroot/home/content/07/8495407/html/.htaccess: IPCCommTimeout not allowed here
So I think the <IfModule> needs to go elsewhere.