# Godaddy updated Apache, now fgetcsv insert into mysql script stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, fgetcsv

First and foremost thank you to anyone who looks at my problem. I am no expert in PHP, Apache, or MySQL so please bear with me. I created a small script that would take a CSV file using fgetcsv to loop through and insert into MySql. This script ran for about 2 months on a CRON job without any issues. I believe at the time Godaddy updated Apache (2.2 to 2.4) it stopped working and returns a 500 internal error. I only found out once I started creating a new script with a different CSV file to compliment my first CSV file which has the same issue. So far I have Googled everything I could think of related to my issue, I have read through many Stackoverflow answers, and sat on hold with Godaddy for 2 hours (They finally said they don't know why, and that they believe something in my script is causing the issue but couldn't advice further). Maybe this has nothing to do with the update, but it is odd this just stopped after such an update.
Before this update my script would take 34 seconds to complete. Now I get a 500 error, if anyone can see something wrong with my script or can tell my why it suddenly stopped I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<?php
session_start();
define("USERACCESSCONTROL", "TRUE");
include 'c_db.php';
if (!$importcsv = fopen("../sync/IVQtyPvt.csv", "r")) {
    echo "could not open file";
} else {
    do {
        If ($i > 1) {
            if ($data[0]) {
                $updatecsv = $inv_con->Prepare("INSERT INTO slave_inventory 
                    (ITEMNMBR,ITMGEDSC,CDC,MAIN,RTO1,RTO2,CDA,KEN,MIS,VAL,
                    KAL,QTYONORD,QTS_CDC,QTS_KEN,QTS_MIS,QTS_KAL,STNDCOST,
                    updated) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ITMGEDSC=?,CDC=?,MAIN=?,RTO1=?,
                    RTO2=?,CDA=?,KEN=?,MIS=?,VAL=?,KAL=?,QTYONORD=?,
                    QTS_CDC=?,QTS_KEN=?,QTS_MIS=?,QTS_KAL=?,STNDCOST=?,
                    updated=NOW()");
                $updatecsv->bind_param("ssiiiiiiiiiiiiiiisiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
                        $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4],
                        $data[5], $data[6], $data[7], $data[8], $data[9],
                        $data[10], $data[11], $data[12], $data[13],
                        $data[14], $data[15], $data[16], $data[1], $data[2],
                        $data[3], $data[4], $data[5], $data[6], $data[7], 
                        $data[8], $data[9], $data[10], $data[11], $data[12],
                        $data[13], $data[14], $data[15], $data[16]);
                $updatecsv->execute();
            }
        }
        $i++;
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($importcsv, ","));
}
?>
```

Here are the repeated entries in my log files.

[Fri Aug 02 04:31:29 2013] [9618523] [dir:error] [client 64.74.215.89:33823] Inside mod_dir, setting document_root to PARENT_DOCUMENT_ROOT : /var/chroot/home/content/23/9618523/html
[fcgid:warn] [client 70.89.210.90:55475] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds
[Fri Aug 02 09:30:34 2013] [9618523] [core:error] [client 70.89.210.90:55475] End of script output before headers:

I have added to my php.ini and php5.ini

```
max_execution_time = 340
max_input_time = 340
```

Added this to my .htaccess (To fix a possible fastcgi issue)

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php5
```

Still no dice
My CSV file has 17 columns, 27000 rows and if there is a better way to do this I would be open to that, but I couldn't get LOAD INFILE to work as I am on shared hosting.

Comment: 500 errors always say why in the logs. Check there

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I posted the three entries in my log files that Godaddy provide for their error logging. Each time my job fires I get the above entries. I can not find the PHP error logs, even when set it doesn't show up in my root, I believe Godaddy doesn't allow you to view them...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445432/apache-500-error-with-php-fun. try that ?

Comment: An Apache 500 error only means php has an error, so an easy way to look this errors is `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` so run your script to look the errors.

Comment: Hi @user1281385 thanks again for your help I tried your link, one of the solution broke my site the other had no affect. ontananza is what? If I can see an error that will point me in the right direction I would be very happy!

Comment: Thanks @ontananza I didn't see your post until after my last. I will try the
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
I have the other already in my php5.ini

Comment: @ontananza Thanks you, I just tried what you suggested by adding them to the PHP file in question. It still gave me the 500 error no more, am I to echo out a variable or should it just display. I added the code at the top below my session_start.

Comment: Can you speed up the script ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user1281385, I've come to the conclusion that Godaddy must have slowed down something on their side and my script doesn't have time to complete the task. I'm going to either switch hosting or break up my csv. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Godaddy was the issue, my scripts started working again on their own. I guess that is what I get for shared hosting on Godaddy. I think I will be switching host soon.